# Javascript Call from ASP.NET GridView - Parameter not getting passed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I use a jQuery popup window to show a new page with a parameter in the query string.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProfile(clickedItem) {
            $.fn.colorbox({ html: '<iframe SCROLLING="Yes"  frameborder="0" src="SiteVP.aspx?siteid="' + clickedItem +  ' width="999" height="550" />', width: "999px", height: "550px", close: 'Continue' });
        }
```

The popup window works just fine, but can't get "siteid" value to be passed. On the new page siteid is "". This is the code in ASP.NET

```
<td style="width:80%">
      <a href="javascript:ShowProfile('<%#Eval("Site").ToString().Replace("'",    "\'")%>')"> <%#Eval("Site") %>
</a>
</td>
```

Can't for the life of me figure out what could possibly be wrong with such a simple javascript call. Please help.

Comment: If you do `alert(clickedItem)` in the function what do you get?

Comment: Shows up correctly. i.e. the clicked param value. Bizarre innit.

Comment: @Mikos - Try `+ encodeURIComponent(clickedItem) +` instead :)

Comment: @diamandiev - could you clarify what you need. I have posted the code I have. Seems to be an iframe issue passing querystring params

Comment: The problem lies in the third party colorbox component. Ive had many problems with third party components. Try doing it manually.

Comment: @diamandiev  - could you clarify what you mean "doing it manually"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like

```
src="SiteVP.aspx?siteid="' + clickedItem +  '
```

should be

```
src="SiteVP.aspx?siteid=' + clickedItem +  '"
```

Note how single and double quotes are moved around